# What is a good way to understand the difference between training RSS/MSE and test RSS for polynomial models?

Tags: machine-learning, splines, training-error

I am trying to understand the difference for training RSS and test RSS for smoothing splines e.g.

$$\hat{g}=\arg \min_g \left(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - g(x_i))^2  + \lambda \int [g^{(m)}(x)]^{2}dx \right)$$

for $m\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ which one has a bigger training RSS and test RSS, as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, and when $\lambda=0$.

I am thinking that for polynomial functions, since as $m$ increases, the $m$th derivative is sub-linear to the previous derivative, it becomes smoother and hence the training RSS decreases for large $\lambda$? But I don't know about the test RSS or for $\lambda=0$.

Comment: 1) Where are you getting this objective function to minimize that involves an integral? // 2) Do you want to know how the residual sum of squares changes as you increase the polynomial degree or how this objective function with the integral changes?

Comment: 1) This is just any arbitrary polynomial, real valued function g which is determined by Polynomial Splines, which extends Lasso to n different cut points (knots) and enforces a smoothing condition $\lambda \int[g^{(m)}(x)]^2 dx$.

Comment: 2) RSS specifically not the objective function, which is however relative to this objective function versus the true values $y_i$

Comment: Then it sounds like you are not interested in the RSS for your models. You are interested in this objective function with the added integral, which is fine. However, if a complex model achieves worse performance than a simple model nested within it, the optimization can always set the additional aspects of the model equal to zero. Assuming nested models, which you appear to have, it seems like, short of computational issues (which could arise), in-sample loss will decrease (or at least not increase) as model complexity increases. Do you see something differently than I do?

Comment: Well it's specifically asking for how RSS changes for the training and testing data as m increases. I don't think that is directly related to loss, only indirectly, since it uses the result of the objective loss.